# Print out of Magento 2 Sales Order

Tags: magento2, sales-order, print

How can I customize print out of Magento 2 sales order ?

Comment: what changes you want to do in print?

Comment: Thanks @Piyush for your reply. I would like to change header and footer of the print out. I am getting lots of things in header and footer. Thanks